# How to replace a subset column with another dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

This has already been asked, but I tried it in proper way, and somehow I am getting an unexpected result.

I have two dataframes `data` and `dky` with many columns.

The code,

`data.loc[(data['source'] == 'DKY_2016'), 'seconds']`

returns:

```
1147    22.80
1154    44.90
1160    45.00
1161    58.35
1162     2.45
```

I want to replace the aforementioned column with `dky['seconds']`, which contains:

```
0     41.22
1     22.80
2     44.90
3     45.00
4     58.35
```

I tried the following code `data.loc[(data['source'] == 'DKY_2016'), 'seconds'] = dky['seconds']`.

But it only giving the `NaN` as the output column

```
1147   NaN
1154   NaN
1160   NaN
1161   NaN
1162   NaN
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you try: `data.loc[(data['source']=='DKY_2016'),'seconds']=dky['seconds'].values.tolist()`

Comment: It worked, Still I didn't understood what was the problem!

Comment: It is because the indices are different. On data you have 1147, 1154, ... while on dky is 0,1,2,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of indexes. `dky['seconds']`, as you can see, has an index of with `0 1 2 3 4`. On the other hand, `data.loc[(data['source'] == 'DKY_2016'), 'seconds']` has an index of `1147 1154 1160 1161 1162`. Since those two are difference, pandas will not assign the one to the other.

Instead, you need to convert the data you're assigning, into a list first, so that it has no index:

```py
data.loc[(data['source'] == 'DKY_2016'), 'seconds'] = dky['seconds'].values.tolist()
```