# Pandas replacing subset of column values with another column based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to check other questions but didn't find what I needed.

I have a dataframe **df**:

```
    a   b
0   6   4
1   5   6
2   2   2
3   7   4
4   3   6
5   5   2
6   4   7
```

and a second dataframe **df2**

```
    d
0   60
1   50
5   50
6   40
```

I want to replace the values in **df['a']** with the values in **df2['d']** - **but only in the relevant indices**.

Output:

```
    a   b
0   60  4
1   50  6
2   2   2
3   7   4
4   3   6
5   50  2
6   40  7
```

All other questions I saw like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047968/how-to-replace-a-subset-column-with-another-dataframe-column-in-pandas) referring to a single value, but I want to replace the values **based on entire column**.

I know I can iterate the rows one by one and replace the values, but I'm looking for a more efficient way.

*Note*: **df2** does not have indices that are not in **df**. I want to replace all values in **df2** with the values of **df**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use indexing:

```
df.loc[df2.index, 'a'] = df2['d']
```

output:

```
    a  b
0  60  4
1  50  6
2   2  2
3   7  4
4   3  6
5  50  2
6  40  7
```